# DevExpress: Escape character to be used in xtratabpage header

Tags: c#, devexpress

Does anybody know how to escape the character "&"? I wanted to use that in a tab page header but instead, it is showing me a blank text. For example, instead of A & B it is showing A _B.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, it is using 2 ampersand &&. Thanks!